# How to select product that have the minimum price out of group of categories and producers?

Tags: sql, oracle, function, min

I have a problem that looks like trivial but I can't make it work. It's in Oracle SQL.
Here is sample of the script:

```
create table product (
product_id number primary key,
name varchar(255)
);

create table producer (
producer_id number primary key,
name varchar(255)
);

create table catalog (
pp_product_id number,
pp_producer_id number,
price number
);


alter table catalog add constraint pp_product_id1 foreign key (pp_product_id) references product (product_id);
alter table catalog add constraint pp_product_id2 foreign key (pp_producer_id) references producer (producer_id);


insert into product (product_id, name) values (1, 'HDD 250 gb');
insert into product (product_id, name) values (2, 'HDD 500 gb');
insert into product (product_id, name) values (3, 'HDD 750 gb');

insert into producer (producer_id, name) values (1, 'Hitachi');
insert into producer (producer_id, name) values (2, 'Corsair');
insert into producer (producer_id, name) values (3, 'Western Digital');

insert into catalog (pp_product_id, pp_producer_id, price) values (1,1, 80);
insert into catalog (pp_product_id, pp_producer_id, price) values (1,3, 60);
insert into catalog (pp_product_id, pp_producer_id, price) values (2,1, 75);
insert into catalog (pp_product_id, pp_producer_id, price) values (2,2, 40);
insert into catalog (pp_product_id, pp_producer_id, price) values (3,2, 63);
insert into catalog (pp_product_id, pp_producer_id, price) values (3,3, 100);
```

So, there are 6 products in total, 3 producers, 3 categories of products (types of HD). What I need is to display CHEAPEST of product, per type of product with producer name associated with that product. Something like:

Western Digital 250 gb 60

Corsair         500 gb 40

Corsair         750 gb 63

This will select cheapest HD in their group (type)

```
select p.name, min (c.price)
from product p, catalog c, producer prc
where c.pp_product_id = p.product_id and prc.producer_id = c.pp_producer_id
group by p.name;
```

...but I can't add producer name? I tried several solutions but none works.

Comment: You cannot add producer name because it is not part of group by

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good use for `row_number()`.  Your data does not have a `type` field, so I invented one in the product table:

```
select *
from (select p.name as product_name, p.type, prod.name as producer_name,
             price,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by p.name order by price ) as seqnum
      from catalog c join
           product p
           on c.pp_product_id = p.product_id join
           producer prod
           on c.pp_producer_id = prod.producer_id
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you want *all* products with the minimum price, use this slight variation:

```
select *
from (select p.name as product_name, p.type, prod.name as producer_name,
             price,
             min(price) over (partition by p.name) as minprice
      from catalog c join
           product p
           on c.pp_product_id = p.product_id join
           producer prod
           on c.pp_producer_id = prod.producer_id
     ) t
where price = minprice;
```

Comment: It says: SQL Error: ORA-00904: "PR"."PRODUCER_ID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier" ?

Comment: Actually product name such as "HDD 250 gb" should be treated as type

Comment: With slight alteration solution is: select *
from (select p.name as product_name, prod.name as producer_name,
price,
ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by p.name order by price ) as seqnum
from catalog c join
product p
on c.pp_product_id = p.product_id join
producer prod
on c.pp_producer_id = prod.producer_id
) t
where seqnum = 1;

Comment: If I apply this solution: select *
from (select p.name as product_name, prod.name as producer_name,price,
ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by p.name order by price ) as seqnum
from catalog c join
product p
on c.pp_product_id = p.product_id join
producer prod
on c.pp_producer_id = prod.producer_id
) t
where seqnum = 1; result is OK but only if there re NOT two (or more) products of same (minimum) price. How should I resolve that?

Answer (score 2):

This should answer your core question. The post address the problem in MySQL but the same concept applies.

http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

Once you get the minimum priced product in the group the rest is just doing joins.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks goes to @Gordon Linoff -with slight change of his code it works for my problem. Just for clarity I am posting solution here:

```
select *
from (select p.name as product_name, prod.name as producer_name,price,
ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by p.name order by price ) as seqnum
from catalog c join
product p
on c.pp_product_id = p.product_id join
producer prod
on c.pp_producer_id = prod.producer_id
) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, I found one another possible answer:

```
SELECT p.name, pr.name, c2.minprice
FROM product p, producer pr, catalog c,
  (SELECT pp_product_id, MIN(price) AS minprice
    FROM catalog c1
    GROUP BY pp_product_id
  ) c2
WHERE p.product_id=c.pp_product_id
AND pr.producer_id=c.pp_producer_id
AND p.product_id  =c2.pp_product_id
AND c.price       =c2.minprice;
```

Output is as this:

HDD 750 gb  Corsair 6300

HDD 500 gb  Corsair 4000

HDD 250 gb  Western Digital 6000